# How to subset a dataframe based on rows that exist in multiple other dataframes?

Tags: pandas

I have created multiple control dataframes (`pos_control_df`, `neg_control_df`) based on columns of the original `df` dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Isolate the control samples
## Samples are "control" if:
## (i) Positive control: "mrna_assignment" column contains substring "pos_control"
## (ii) Negative control: "mrna_assignment" column contains substring "neg_control"
## (iii) standard Affymetrix spike control probeset:  "category" column contains substring "control->affx"
## (iv) antigenomic background probes: "category" column contains substring "control->bgp->antigenomic"

pos_neg_ctl_df = df.loc[((df["mrna_assignment"].str.contains("pos_control")) | (df["mrna_assignment"].str.contains("neg_control"))),:] 

probe_ctl_df = df.loc[((df["category"].str.contains("control->affx")) | (df["category"].str.contains("control->bgp->antigenomic"))),:]
```

Now, I want to create `sample_df` by subsetting `df` to keep samples that don't exist in either `pos_neg_ctl_df` or `probe_ctl_df`.

Now, I want to create `sample_df` by subsetting `df` by keeping only rows that are not in any of the control dataframes.

Here, I'm able to subset the `df` by the `pos_neg_ctl_df` dataframe. But I'm not sure how to simultaneously subset `df` by multiple dataframes (i.e., `pos_neg_ctl_df` or `probe_ctl_df` dataframes).

```
merged_posneg_control = df.reset_index().merge(pos_neg_ctl_df, how='left', indicator=True)
sample_df = merged_posneg_control[merged_posneg_control['_merge']=='left_only']
sample_df = sample_df.set_index("Gene Symbol")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use merge to do that.
You did not give example for your dataframe but let's assume you have an identifier column named 'id', you will do:

```
sample_df = df.merge(right='pos_neg_ctl_df', how='right', on='id')
sample_df = sample_df .merge(right='probe_ctl_df', how='right', on='id')
sample_df = sample_df .merge(right='std_affy_control_df', how='right', on='id')
sample_df = sample_df .merge(right='antigenomic_bg_control', how='right', on='id')
```

Comment: The first line of code raised `TypeError: Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a <class 'str'> was passed`

Comment: Plaase post 'pos_neg_ctl_df'